# Tailwind css installation, rebuild won't stop

Tags: installation, tailwind-css

I try to install Tailwind CSS following the instructions on the official page.
But as I tried to input the following instruction which starts the Tailwind CLI build process, the following occurred.

> npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URfC0.png)
And it's still rebuilding even after ten minutes.
I have no idea what is going on.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `--watch` means it will keep running. If you run the command without `--watch` what happens?

Answer (score 2):

The `--watch` command will make it run continiously. To put an end to it just press and hold `CTRL` then `C`

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to end it with control + c with no issues

Answer (score 0):

In `tailwind.config.js`, stick to the essential folders, mine had to check thousands of plugin files before building, so updated it to limit the files to check

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "../views/**/*.{php,js,html}",
    "../js/app/**/*.{php,js}"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```